# Skewed classification results

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am dealing with a classification problem with 10 classes.  More or less, the number of samples per class is same. Yet I am getting a skewed classification result. By changing the gamma value in the Gaussian kernel SVM, the samples are getting classified to one particular class in most cases. That is, when the gamma value is large, most of the samples are getting classified to class A. For smaller gamma values, most of the samples are getting classified to class B. With some other gamma values, they go to some other class etc. Can you suggest why this is happening? How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: The Gaussian kernel maps the samples to a different space based on the Gaussian RBF function. It might be the case that in this new space, different classes looks the same. I would suggest you consider feature selection, multi-class SVM such as the nice MSVMPack or try different classifiers. It is not clear from the question which approach did you take to deal with the classification of more than two classes. You may also try with more than one approach including one-to-all, one-to-one and the heirarchical model.